# How to capture all fired events when I click in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I've got a comprehensive navigation menu on a page. It has a lot of jQuery stuff and different attached events.

Then I have an annoying bug in all version of Internet Explorer, including version 11.

I wonder if there is a way to monitor all fired events when I click in a specific place of the page.

Comment: Appending some code to the question and describing the bug would be helpful. Use `e.target` to find the origin of the object clicked. https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Thanks for your response Shikkediel. That's exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cheers, glad to have pointed in the right direction. :-)

Comment: In F12 tools, Emulation, what version is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer:

> "Appending some code to the question and describing the bug would be
>   helpful. Use e.target to find the origin of the object clicked.
>   api.jquery.com/event.target –  Shikkediel"

Mini implementation details:

Add jQuery:

```
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> </head>
```

And the following code somewhere between `<body></body>` tags:

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<div>
    <p>
        <strong><span>click</span></strong>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
    $("body").click(function(event) {
        $("#log").html("clicked: " + event.target.nodeName);
    });
</script>
```

Once you click on the place on the screen you would find out which element was triggered.